# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "qué va"?

Tags: historia, locuciones

El [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=O6eco2ky2D6USmsCih) explica el significado de la expresión "qué va":

> **h) qué va**. Se usa como negación enfática: «—*¿Le pasa a usted algo? —¡Qué va! Estoy muy bien*» (Sampedro Sonrisa [Esp. 1985]).

Sin embargo, la expresión por si sola no parece tener mucho significado, o no es obvio que se trata de una negación por las palabras que la componen.

¿Tiene el origen de la frase una explicación para su verdadero significado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En realidad el origen en este caso es sencillo:

> —¡Ajá! ¿Conque sabía?
>   —¡Qué va a saber, señor! Si es que está distraída; si es que El Patas la tiene asina.
>
> Tomás Carrasquilla, "La marquesa de Yolombó", 1928 (Colombia).

Aunque la expresión sea una exclamación, queda más claro su origen si se pone como interrogación:

> —¿Le pasa a usted algo?
>   —¿Qué va a pasarme, si estoy muy bien?

Como repetir el verbo suele ser redundante, la frase "qué va a pasarme" se queda al final en "qué va", cambiando las interrogaciones por exclamaciones, dándole así más énfasis a la negación.

Curiosamente, yo pensaba que la expresión sería más antigua, pero los primeros casos que encuentro son ya del siglo XX.